# how make index of primary key be used on SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a topic_data table, with **id** as the **primary key** and also a topic_id_timestamp_index index on topic_id and timestamp with topic_id in ascending order and timestamp in descending order.

When i created the second index i run the **CLUSTER** command based on that index.

When i run the following query the **topic_id_timestamp_index** index is being used.

```
SELECT id, topic_id, "timestamp", col4, col5, ... , col20 
FROM topic_data 
where id in ('idval_1', 
             'idval_2', 
             'idval_3', 
             'idval_4', 
             'idval_5', 
             'idval_6', 
             'idval_7', 
             'idval_8', 
             'idval_9') 
and topic_id in (topic_id_1, 
                 topic_id_2) 
and "timestamp" between '2017-01-01' and '2017-10-1' ;
```

If i select order by timestamp ascending then index of primary key is being used. I suppose this is happening due to when i run the CLUSTER command data were reorganizedand with timestamp in descending order and postgress decided that primary index should be used instead.

When i run a query and the primary index is used the query execution time is 20 ms. When the topic_id_timestamp_index is used the exec time is 250 ms.

So my question is how can i rearrange my query so as **the index of primary key** to be used all the times?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If `id` is a primary key you will get at most 9 result rows from this query.